# standard video full support all browsers

Tags: firefox, video

I use a standard video tag in my website. But I want at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari to support my files. Can I put backup files somewhere?

```
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src="" class="sandbox"></video>

<li movieurl="media/fiat.mp4" moviesposter="http://www.jingleweb.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/logo-Fiat-Zomer-Radio.png">
    <p>1.</p>
        LG TV commercial
</li>
```

That list item is just an example, it's in a list off course. I load an mp4 file in there. But Firefox doesn't support that. So my question is if it's possible to put a backup file in there so Firefox can play that one?

Here is the js that controls the list:

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
        $("#playlist li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })

    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
```

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on HTML5 video. It will answer your question and show you the correct syntax. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: Well the problem is that I use a playlist. And they all talk about when you have only one video.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do what you're asking in your updated message. I had a quick stab at it and the following does what you're after.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video test</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
          $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
              $("#videoarea").attr({
                  "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
                  "poster": "",
                  "autoplay": "autoplay"
              })
              $("#playlist li.active").removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");

              return false;
          })

          $("#videoarea").attr({
              "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
              "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
          })
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src="" class="sandbox"></video>

  <ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="video-short.mp4" moviesposter="poster.png">
        <p>1.</p>
            LG TV commercial
    </li>
    <li movieurl="video-short.ogv" moviesposter="poster.png">
        <p>1.</p>
            LG TV commercial
    </li>
  </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Although I don't know the context in which you'll be using this it would certainly be better practice to use the source element within the video element to support different browsers. Your visitors are unlikely to realise they need to choose a different format should they see a 'format not supported' message for the default video file.

The HTML video tag allows you to specify more than one source for different browsers to play. As shown by this snippet from the [Video section](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) of Dive Into HTML5, which has a wealth of information on the subject.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
  <source src="pr6.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
  <source src="pr6.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis">
</video>
```

Each `<source>` tag specifies a different media source file, type and codec. The `.mp4` file is meant for browsers like Safari, the `.webm` file is for Chrome and the `.ogv` file is for Firefox.

Adding the `type` attribute and including the codec will help the browser work out if it can play the file.

> The benefit of going to all this trouble is that the browser will
>   check the type attribute first to see if it can play a particular
>   video file. If a browser decides it can’t play a particular video, it
>   won’t download the file. Not even part of the file. You’ll save on
>   bandwidth, and your visitors will see the video they came for, faster.

The codec value is not required but as you can see, it'll probably save your viewers and you some wasted bandwidth.

In order to serve your video in the different formats you'll need to encode the video file yourself using a tool like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) or maybe ffmpeg.

Finally, should your viewers not be able to play the three source files you've specified you can add some alternative content.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2">
  <source src="pr6.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
  <source src="pr6.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis">

  <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
      [...]
  </object>
</video>
```

Take a look at the Dive Into HTML5 Video Page for more info.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks I understand this, but i'm using a playlist of videos with only one videoarea. I'll edit my question with some js to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Please help me out, I kind of have a deadline in 3 hours ;)

Comment: Can I for example change the place where I get the source from? Like in the javascript of something like that?

Comment: Hey Luc. Afraid I didn't see your update until this morning. I've updated the answer along the lines of you updated question.

Comment: That's ok, great that you still want to help me. I'm going to work with this, let's what it does! Thanks a lot! (past deadline, but tweaking is always possible ;) )

Comment: It works, but they both show up in my playlist. Is it possible to h=show just the one the browser supports?

Comment: No problem. It is possible to hide and show list items based on the browser your viewer is using but that isn't a great idea. [Chris Coyier gives a good overview of why](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/).
Is there any reason you'd like to have the browser specific video versions in a list rather than as a `<source>` element?